# Prove that for $\forall x \in (0,1]$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> Prove that $\forall x \in (0,1]$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$

This is a completely obvious statement (it was taken for granted in another proof) and yet I cannot seem to come up with a strictly formal proof. Of course, if we take $A$ to be the set of $n$ such that $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}-x \geq 0$ and show that this set is bounded above, then $\sup(A)$ (or $\max(A)$ since $A \in \mathbb{N}$) will be the desired $n$. We could show that $A$ is bounded using the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = -x < 0$, so there is an $N$ such that all $n>N \notin A$. Is this the right direction or am I just overthinking it?

Comment: The desired $n$ should satisfy $nx\leq 1$ but $(n+1)x\geq 1$.  The mapping $n\mapsto nx$ is monotone and has value $0$ for $n=0$ and value $>1$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Choose $n$ to be the largest satisfying $nx\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Can you prove that for all $y\geq 1$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\leq y\leq n+1$?

Answer (score 1):

What about $n=\mathrm{floor}(\frac{1}{x})$ ?

Comment: OP is looking for a proof, not an example.

Comment: An example is a proof of existence...

Comment: OP is trying to prove his claim for all $x$.

Comment: $\mathrm{floor}\frac{1}{x}$ does exist for all $x\in (0,1]$, and satisfies the property. So it proves the statement.

Comment: I think you'll need to prove that it satisfies the property.

Comment: By definition,$\mathrm{floor}(\frac{1}{x})$ is the unique integer satisfying $n\leq\frac{1}{x}<n+1$. In particular, for $n=\mathrm{floor}(\frac{1}{x})$, we have $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Or maybe you're saying I should prove the existence of the floor function ?

Comment: Given the context of the question, I don't think the OP can assume that the floor function satisfies this (it would be too easy, almost a circular argument: to prove $n+1 \geq x \geq n$, assume that there is a function that returns the integer $n$ satisfying $n+1 \geq x \geq n$). The challenge remains to prove that there **exists** an integer $n$ such that $n \leq \frac 1 x \leq n+1$. (I.e. yes, prove the existence of the floor function.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get quite directly from the [Archimedean Property of the Real Numbers](http://planetmath.org/archimedeanproperty) that there exists some $n$ such that $x \leq \frac 1 n$. In particular, suppose that this $n$ is the natural number giving the closest $\frac 1 n$ to $x$, i.e. that there is no $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $x \leq \frac 1 m < \frac 1n$. (There must be such a 'closest' $n$ -- suppose there is only one $n$, then it's that. Suppose there are several -- then one of them will be closest because the real numbers are well-ordered.)

Then we can get the conclusion we want by contradiction. Take $\frac 1 {n+1}$. It is clear that $\frac 1 {n+1} < \frac 1 n$. Then suppose $x \leq \frac 1 {n+1} < \frac 1 n$. That's impossible, because we supposed that $n$ was the closest, above. Then we must have that $\frac 1 {n+1} \leq x \leq \frac 1 n$.

Answer (score 0):

Set :

$$X:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}^*| \frac{1}{n}\geq x\} $$

This set is non empty because $1\in X$. Furthermore it is clear that if $n\in X$ then any $l\leq n$ will be in $X$ as well : $l\in X$. We would like to show that $X$ is bounded above. Hence (because of what I have written before) if we find $a>0$ such that $a\notin X$ then $X$ is bounded above by $a$.

Now to show that there exist an integer $a$ such that $a\notin X$ i.e. :

$$x>\frac{1}{a}\Leftrightarrow a>\frac{1}{x} $$

And this is the archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ that allows us to do this (one of the fundamental axiom of $\mathbb{R}$). Hence $X$ is bounded above, and as a non-empty set of integers it must have a maximum $n$. The maximum of $X$ clearly verifies (because $n+1\notin X$) :

$$\frac{1}{n+1}<x\leq \frac{1}{n} $$